# Is there any way in R we can find "text" in one column put the same value in another column in R data-frame?

Tags: r

Suppose I have data-frame x. It has column "A" and "B".

```
A        B
a b      a b
c d      c d
e f      e f
a b      a b
a b
a b      a b
a b      a b
a b
a b
a b
a b
```

I want to display something like this.

```
A        B
a b      a b
c d      c d
e f      e f
a b      a b
a b      a b
a b      a b
a b      a b
a b      a b
a b      a b 
a b      a b
a b      a b
```

Basically I want to do filter on x.A for value "a b", so that I can get exact same value on x.B. For column B I have only "a b" and " " values for that. I want to convert " " to "a b" in B column.

I have tried using gsub, sub, filter with regex but after cleaning data if I export this .csv file in excel I am not getting correct output what I want.

Comment: It's helpful to see what you've tried even if it hasn't worked. Are you just trying to subset for when the values in A and B are the same? I'm also not sure what exporting to csv would have to do with the issue

Comment: aren't you just doing `df$B = df$A` ??

Comment: No, because B and A has some different values too.

Comment: I want to fill value of blanks in B when A has a value "a b". And want to fill with "a b". Its a text.

Comment: @camille I want to fill the value for B with "a b" when  A has a value "a b".

Comment: @divibisan library(plyr)
junk$nm <- revalue(junk$nm, c("B"="b")) ... this can work but I want filter for "A" column. because "A" has multiple values but I want to do that for particular one only.

Comment: @divibisan , I want to something like this: if A == a b then B == a b.

Comment: Have you looked at the accepted answer on the linked question? You need to change the names of the column that is being checked in the conditional and the column that is being changed

Comment: I have to use condition here. If I have to do in Excel it's simple. I want filter on "A" with value "a b".  then I will get all "a b" from "A". and for "B" side I will get either "a b" or " ". Instead of " " I want "a b" on "B" side.

Comment: But I want this to automate in R.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to check whether column `B` has any value. If yes, keep this, if not, put the value of column `A` there, you can use ifelse:

```
df$B <- ifelse(df$B == "", df$A, df$B)
```

Comment: I want to check if A has value "a b". Then B's value should be "a b" only. but in some  values there are blanks and in some "a b". Instead of blanks I want "a b" only.

Comment: In that case it should be:
df$B <- ifelse(df$A == "a b", df$A, df$B)

Comment: it's not working.